# Passing component props into a string in ReactJS/NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, next.js, react-props

I have the following component

```
import Link from "next/link";
import styles from "./product.module.css";

export default function Product(props) {
  return (
    <div className={styles.product}>
      <Link href={props.link}>
        <img src={props.img} alt={props.name} />
      </Link>
      <Link href={props.link}>
        <h3>{props.name}</h3>
      </Link>
      <span>{props.price}</span>
              <button onClick={handleClick}>
          Add to Bag 
        </button>
    </div>
  );  
}
```

I am trying to add an onClick named handleClick and for testing, I am trying to run a console log containing the following `{props.name} has been added to the basket at a price of {props.price}`

However, onClick I receive the following error: `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props')`

What is the process to fix this?

The code for the handleClick function is below.

```
const handleClick = (e) => {
        console.log(`${this.props.name} + "added to basket at price of " + ${this.props.price} + "`);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In function component, it does not have context about `this`. Why don't use props as you have used in return function.

```
export default function Product(props) {
    const handleClick = (e) => {
        console.log(`${props.name} + "added to basket at price of " + ${props.price} + "`);
    }
    
    return (
        <div className={styles.product}>
            <Link href={props.link}>
                <img src={props.img} alt={props.name} />
            </Link>
            <Link href={props.link}>
                <h3>{props.name}</h3>
            </Link>
            <span>{props.price}</span>
            <button onClick={handleClick}>
                Add to Bag
            </button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: I tried this initially and it says `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: props`

Comment: Where is function declared? It will work in my edit.

Comment: The function is declared in the component/product.js file? Should it be declared on the page that it is called?

Comment: By the way, if you want to declare function in somewhere esle, check how access variables in function by concept Closure in js: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work#:~:text=Whenever%20a%20function%20is%20declared%20in%20JavaScript%20a%20closure%20is%20created.&text=A%20closure%20is%20created%20when,time%20a%20function%20is%20called.

Comment: It isn't declared somewhere else, it is declared in the product component @Viet Dinh

Comment: I see I needed to declare the function above the return but within the default function!

Comment: Thank you for the help!